# Changing text (link) color onclick with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, function, onclick, textcolor

I can not change the color of the text with js. Showing and Hiding div tags are working great but color can't be changed. btw, in my css file there are no styles for those links.

HTML:

```
    <ul>
    <li id="web_link"><a href="#">WEB</a></li>
    <li id="design_link"><a href="#">DESIGN</a></li>
    <li id="photo_link"><a href="#">PHOTO</a></li>
    </ul>

<div id="web_proekti">
 Some elements
</div>

<div id="design_proekti">
Some elements 
</div>  

<div id="photo_proekti">
Some elements 
</div>
```

Javascript file:

```
$('#web_link').click(function()
{
    $('#web_proekti').show();
    $('#design_proekti').hide();
    $('#photo_proekti').hide();
    $('#design_link').css('color','#999');
    $('#photo_link').css('color','#999');

}
);

$('#design_link').click(function()
{
    $('#design_proekti').show();
    $('#web_proekti').hide();
    $('#photo_proekti').hide();
    $('#web_link').css('color','#999');
    $('#photo_link').css('color','#999');

}
);

$('#photo_link').click(function()
{
    $('#photo_proekti').show();
    $('#design_proekti').hide();
    $('#web_proekti').hide();
    $('#design_link').css('color','#999');
    $('#web_link').css('color','#999');

}
);
```

Comment: You're selecting the `LI` element, not the `A` element inside of the `LI` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing color of the `<li>`, but not the link color.

To change the color of the `<a>`, try

```
 $('#photo_link a').css('color','#999');
```

instead of

```
 $('#photo_link').css('color','#999');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the color from the `<a>` tag itself by adding a simple `a` after its parent id in the js:

```
$('#web_link').click(function()
{
    $('#web_proekti').show();
    $('#design_proekti').hide();
    $('#photo_proekti').hide();
    $('#design_link a').css('color','#999');
    $('#photo_link a').css('color','#999');

}
);

$('#design_link').click(function()
{
    $('#design_proekti').show();
    $('#web_proekti').hide();
    $('#photo_proekti').hide();
    $('#web_link a').css('color','#999');
    $('#photo_link a').css('color','#999');

}
);

$('#photo_link').click(function()
{
    $('#photo_proekti').show();
    $('#design_proekti').hide();
    $('#web_proekti').hide();
    $('#design_link a').css('color','#999');
    $('#web_link a').css('color','#999');

}
);
```